# How to reference javascript files from another project?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm currently trying to write some unit test on some javascript files.  My first and foremost problem with that is that my test files are in a different project than the actual javascript files.  I'm running VS2008, and in my test project, I have included a reference of the actual project file.  Assuming I'm writing my tests in an html file, does anyone have a solution to solve the above problem?

Thanks.

EDIT (from op's own answer to this question):

Sorry my bad. I copied a js file which had an error on it.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, don't you just need to figure out the relative path from your unit test HTML file to your projects JavaScript file(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could put the path to the JavaScript files you want to test in your main unit test HTML file...

Or you could put some hard links in the same folder as your unit test project and reference those...

Or you could add a virtual directory to IIS or whatever under your unit test's IIS folder that points to the original project and write your script tag to reference that...